# add new row to table with 2 drop down list- how do i change the name of the select

Tags: javascript, xhtml, asp-classic

I would really appreciate if someone could help me. for two days I've tried to figure this out alone but its not working.

I'm writing a shopping list to my project at school. I have a table (shopinglist) that contains the form.

In the form I have 2 drop down lisst, one (product) is getting the values from my database and the second one (quantity) is constant numners.  Next to these two I have 2 buttons add and remove.

When pressing add I want to add a new row with the same stuff.

The problem is that I can't (or maybe don't know how to) change the select name according to the row number. I mean like

One last thing- the row will be added only if the user choose from both selection, not only from one.

here is my code: the javascript add and remove functions:

```
 function addRow(tableID) {

if (document.getElementById("product").value!="dafult" && document.getElementById("quantity").value!="zero") 
{
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<=colCount; i++) {
             var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                 newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
              switch(newcell.childNodes[1].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[1].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[1].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[1].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;

                }
            }
              newcell.childNodes[1].visible = true;
              table.rows[rowCount-1].cells[2].style.visibility="hidden" ;
            }
            else
          {
            if (document.getElementById("product").value!="dafult" && document.getElementById("quantity").value=="zero") 

                 alert("please choose quantity") ;
               if (document.getElementById("product").value=="dafult" && document.getElementById("quantity").value!="zero") 
                alert("please choose product") ; 
               if (document.getElementById("product").value=="dafult" && document.getElementById("quantity").value=="zero") 
                    alert("please choose product and qantity") ;
           }
            }

        function deleteRow(i){
        if (document.getElementById("product").value!="dafult" && document.getElementById("quantity").value!="zero") 
            document.getElementById('shopinglist').deleteRow(i)
        else
            alert("you can't delete row before adding it");
}
```

---

and the HTML and ASP

```
<table border="0" id="shopinglist">
<caption valign="top" style="width:90%;height:35px; color:green ;"/> your order 
<tr><td></td><td> product</td> <td> quantity</td></tr>
<tr>
<form name="juices">
    <%      
    set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    rs.open "SELECT ID, [Product-Name] ,[size-liter],[Customer price] FROM Product GROUP BY  ID,[Product-Name] ,[Product].[size-liter],[Product].[Customer price] ", conn
    %>
<td>
<select name="product" id="product" width="10" >
<option value="dafult" selected>בחר מוצר מהרשימה</option>
<%
do while not rs.EOF %>
<option value=<%=rs("Product-Name")%> > juice<%=rs("Product-Name")%>   <%=rs("size-liter")%>  liter<%=rs("Customer price")%>  $</option>
<%
rs.MoveNext()
loop
rs.close %> 
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="quantity" id="quantity">
<option value="zero" selected="selected">0</option>
<option value="one">1</option>
<option value="two">2</option>
<option value="three">3</option>
<option value="four">4</option>
<option value="five">5</option>
<option value="six">6</option>
<option value="seven">7</option>
<option value="eight">8</option>
<option value="nine">9</option>
<option value="ten">10</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="button" value="add" onclick="addRow('shopinglist')" id="addbutton"/>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="button" value="delete"onclick="deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)" id="remove"/>
</td>
</tr>
         </form>
```

Comment: Your sentence is unfinished: "The problem is that I can't (or maybe don't know how to) change the select name according to the row number. I mean like ??"

Comment: like-at the first add button press i want it to creat 2 drop down list when the first select will be like <select name=product_2  and then the scond one will be select name=quantity_2 
at the next add row prees select name=product_3 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

IE will not let you change the name of an element after you add it to the page. The way this is written, you would have to actually alter the string containing the select before setting innerHTML

```
newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML.replace(/(\<select.+?name=".+?)"/, $1 + rowCount + i + "\"");
```

NOT TESTED... something like that...

Comment: no it's not working.. no i can't add a row at all...  is that jquery?

Comment: did you completely miss the "NOT TESTED... something like that..."?

Comment: :) i'm cluelesss...i really start to belive there is no way i could  do that..there is no answer to this kinda problem anywhere on the web..

Comment: yes there is... alter the name before setting innerHTML.. that simple.

Comment: try creating the row contents from scratch with javascript instead of using table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML

Comment: and then what? cause i tried it already.. 
var sel1 = document.createElement('select') ; 
sel1.name='quantity_'+row ;
like that?

Comment: its okay.. do you understand html dom and javascript?

Comment: html javascript asp and about the dom i'm not sure :)

Comment: no IE wont let you set name on an element after it is created... newcell.innerHTML = "<select name='quantity_" + row + "'>...</select>"

Comment: oh the other problem is that the product drop down list is populate by sql query..

Comment: woowwwwww i think it's working!!!! thank you very very very much!
one more question- the name is different in each select so how can i identify which select was created now and give it the right name?

Comment: now im confused.. how do i do it in java script? the sql query is a server side and that where the option comes from

Comment: rofl... NO!.. give the new select an id... set the innerhtml of the cell.. getElementById the new select box... copy children on original select...

Comment: there are easier/cleaner ways to do all of this, i am just trying to help you understand your original problem

Comment: im a rofi :) and i thought i could do something brilliant for my project but know i understand that it's really complicated for me.. 
these steps you pointed up i need to do before the innerHTML?

Comment: im sorry..didn't mean to upset you..
and im a girl :) thank you you've been kind

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example https://gist.github.com/957827 that you could start with. It is radically different but simpler than yours.

I don't have a IE6,7,8 to test it properly but it should be something like the example.

One more comment, id's must be unique. And you shouldn't use them on a row of a table that you will copy.

Comment: although this is much prettier... you cannot change "name" attribute of element in IE

Comment: True, there are solutions for that problem. But it was to start with something cleaner and simpler. May be he has some luck anyway and can make his homework on Firefox or Chrome

Comment: his original question says it all... this does not even address it?

Comment: Yes, here i am. rofl @ ie9.. 2 bad there is at least like 1 other browser to worry about ;-)... and she probably wouldnt have asked the ? if ie9 was the target because she wouldnt have had the problem.... but good going man!! nice work!!!!!